# Tooltip like information popup

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I have a two `treeview` and a drag and drop functionality between them.  
When I drag things from one control to the other I want a popup to say something like :

```
3 item(s) added.
```

A `tooltip` is designed to be on a mouse over for info on a control or something but it has interesting attributes like a fade in and out effect etc..

My other option would be to use a `label` but I don't want to make it appear and then disappear.. also the `label` don't seem to be the control i'm looking for.

It's something commonly used no ? Is there a control between these two that suit my needs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use System.Windows.Forms.Form and set some properties with this values:

```
f.FormBorderStyle = None;
f.MaximizeBox = false;
```

You can also fix its size.

This will give you base to start from.
And now about the fading. This can be accomplished using `Opacity` property from 0% to 100% in time frame. This is basicy all you neet to start.

For showing this popup just use regular code like this:

```
PopupForm f = new PopupForm();
f.Show();
```